# Get browser bookmarks via javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, bookmarks

we want to provide an online bookmark service to our customers. Therefor it would be nice to provide also a function to store local bookmarks into our online tool. This shouldn't be done automatically - the user should confirm this action (only in case someone thinks I want to spy users data).
I'm looking for a while now, but I found only that there is no solution, because it's a security risk. Is there a way or already a tool for such a functionality in Javascript?

Regards

Answer (score 10):

This is *completely* impossible.

You need to write a browser addon.

Comment: Yeah, I feared to hear that. I think I'll provide a solution where a user can upload a NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file. IE8 and FF 3 can export into html, so this could be a way for me.

Comment: @Adam: Sure, but my intension is not to do something bad, so it wouldn't be a problem for if the user has to agree via confirm dialog. By hook or by crook it's not possible.

Comment: I know that you can write a browser extension for Chrome that will allow access to bookmarks after user confirmation, but I am glad that it is not natively possible, as you just might be the *only* person who would do so without a bad intention :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way or already a tool for such a functionality in Javascript?

Nope, definitely not. Maybe for browser extensions - if it's possible even for them.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't any solution to do this via javascript. The only solution I can think of is to use a Java Applet to read the client's computer and look for the bookmark.

Another way is you can ask them to export their favorites to a file and upload to your website.

Comment: *to use a Java Applet to read the client's computer and look for the bookmark* which is also impossible unless the applet is signed and the user allows local file system access explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Prompt the user to upload the bookmarks file: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/i1r3CgqvgCI