# How to get information like history from your browser and place them in a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am new to programming. i was wondering if it is possible to get the favourites or history that we commonly add in our browser.

Example : let say i want to display the favourites that i have in my browser in a div element as a link to the website or url. or maybe i would like to get a youtube's videos thumbnail and display it in a div.

is this possible to do this using javascript, if not which language is most commonly used in such situations.

Comment: This is not possible to prevent bookmark or history spying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get browser bookmarks via javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122646/get-browser-bookmarks-via-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

If something like this were possible I'm pretty sure it would be exploited to breach user privacy left, right and centre.

You can use the JavaScript `window.history` function to automatically navigate back and forward from a page or to navigate to a specific part of the history, but this is limited to the current tab a user has open or the browser window (if no tabs are supported).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: if this is not possible then how is it that when we download a new app or software it might using our informations. like when we download a net privacy software then it can filter all our searches.

Comment: Well for one, downloaded software is almost never coded using HTML, CSS or JavaScript. Downloaded software can read data stored in files on your system. Websites can't. If they could, I'm pretty sure the internet wouldn't be half as popular as it is today.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Maybe if you write a browser related plugin, extension or addon, however they call it.

**Chrome:** http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html

**Firefox:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Places_Developer_Guide#Identifying_Items_in_the_Bookmark_System