# How can I get the browser URL history using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube-api, mozilla

I would like to get all the URL's of YouTube videos watched on a browser.This is used to populate an auto complete option.I researched on this topic, and none of them satisfactorily answered the question.I don't even know if it's possible.To be clear:When we type www.youtube.com, our browser shows a drop-down list of YouTube pages we have seen before.I want access to these URLs.How can I do this?

Comment: It's not possible - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205651/how-to-get-information-like-history-from-your-browser-and-place-them-in-a-div-el

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The YouTube API has a videos watched feed: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/01/watch-history-comes-to-api.html

Edit: Theres a pretty good SO question on retrieving the users history:[How do you access browser history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805/how-do-you-access-browser-history)

Comment: That looks good!But my end users don't log in to their YouTube account to watch videos, so the videos they watch would not be in their watch history.However the browser will store them.So is there a way to get the data from the browser?

Comment: While the link in the edit looked promising, it says it can only tell if a URL was visited.Though it may be good for checking for a few URL's, doing so for millions of videos is out of the question.Thanks anyway, I guess I have no other go but to do with the YouTube's watch history.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read the browser's history using JavaScript code that runs in the context of a web page as it would be a security breach. You would not want to allow a site to know wich other sites you visited.

However, it might be possible if you are developing a browser extension that the user will install. Have a look at this  for chrome http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html

Comment: Yes, I understand it.I saw this in many places, but is it possible to ask for the user's permission to share with us that information?

Comment: That looks cool!I am developing a web application , can I use this?

Comment: @Aravind, I have never developed extensions and have no idea if you could create one that exposes an API that could then be used by some JavaScript code that runs in the context of a web page, but if you can I believe the answer would be yes ;)

Comment: It's the same story with me.I have no experience working with extensions.So it's probably best to just use YouTube Watch History for the initial release of my application.Thanks for the information.:)