# How to read a Bookmarklet from java?

Tags: javascript, java

There is a Javascript that needs to be executed after hitting the page in the browser. This javascript runs only when it is stored as a bookmark in the browser. My task is to execute this javascript that is stored in the bookmark in the browser using a java code.

On Googling, I find that the URL can be bookmarked via a java code. But I dont find how to read the bookmark. Please suggest how can I read it through java code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer which said that is impossible to do it unless you do a browser extension:

[Get browser bookmarks via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122646/get-browser-bookmarks-via-javascript)

Although another answer talks about upload the browser bookmark file and read it in javascript :

> Inside the "...\Chrome\User Data\Default\" directory are two files. "Bookmarks", and "Bookmarks.bak". One is for your current bookmarks, and the other one (with the .bak extension) signifies that it is a bookmarks backup, if anything goes wrong. Bookmarks.bak gets overwritten every time you close Chrome.
>
> Bookmarks in Chrome exist as a virtual filesystem. Meaning, that all
>   your bookmarks are really just stored in one file, but appear as an
>   actual filesystem inside Chrome.
>
> You only have to copy that file, and back it up somewhere. And if you
>   want to recovery your bookmarks, simply copy/paste the "Bookmarks"
>   file you backed-up, back in to the directory you took it from.
>
> Chrome must be closed prior to doing this.
>
> Hope this helps.
>
> (and btw, try opening the "Bookmarks" file with a text editor like
>   Notepad =])

[Location of chrome bookmarks](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/i1r3CgqvgCI)