# XSS attack: Stealing bookmarks

Tags: xss, bookmarks

Is it possible for someone to steal my bookmarks through a cross-site scripting attack? Is it a similar procedure to cookie stealing?

Comment: So, when you are asking if something is possible with XSS, you can pretty much ask if it is possible with JavaScript. And if you did, you may have discovered this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122646/get-browser-bookmarks-via-javascript . In short, no, it is not possible without a major vulnerability in the browser itself.

Comment: Thanks,it's pretty clear!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't steal bookmarks unless you discover a new browser bug.

But for a long time you could steal some of the browser's history using JavaScript. Actually, this might still be a possibility: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62351/xss-history-stealing